# Querying for a blank answer - lack of a row in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a form that users fill out when a patient gets transferred to another location.

The relevant part of the form looks like this:
[image]

I want to count the number of patients that have a no `Date of Return`.

Relevant tables -

form_names - list of forms

```
select id, name from form_names where id = 47

id    name
----- ----------------------
47    Transfer of Health Information
```

form_items - listing of the questions for each of the form (`form_name`).

```
select id, form_name, text from form_items where form_name = 47

id          form_name   text
----------- ----------- ------------------------------------
1147        47          Date of Transfer:
1148        47          Sending Facility:
1155        47          Date of Return:
```

form_records - a record stating that a particular patient (`pid`) filled out a form (`form_name`).

```
select id, pid, date, form_name From form_records where pid = 260 and form_name = 47

id          pid         date                    form_name
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------
16409       260         2013-04-24 09:33:29.000 47
```

Now, the last relevant table is the form_answers table. **Only completed answers will be populate in this table.**

As you can see, since the `Date of Return` value was never filled out in the form, it never will be in this table:

```
select id, form_record, form_item, text from form_answers where form_record = 16409

id                   form_record form_item   text
-------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------------------------------------
354535               16409       1147        04-24-2013
354536               16409       1148        Lawrence Jail
354537               16409       1149        Lawrence County Hospital
354538               16409       1151        NKMA
```

I've tried something like this, and it doesn't work:

```
select
        count(*)
from
        form_names fn
                inner join form_items fi on fn.id = fi.form_name
                inner join form_records fr on fn.id = fr.form_name             
                left outer join form_answers fa on fr.id = fa.form_record and fi.id = fa.form_item
where
        fn.name like '%Transfer of Health Information%'
        and dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, fr.date)) = dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()))
        and fi.text like '%receiving facility%'
        and fa.id is NULL
```

**How do I find a count of patients that have NO Date Returned field**

Comment: where not exists, or outer join = null

Comment: How does your query "not work"?

Comment: When I run the query, my count is 0. When 1 should be the desired result. Edit - When commenting out the `left outer join` and `fa.id is NULL`, I return 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the join on the answer is not correct.  You need to join both to the item and to the fr.id:

```
select count(*)  -- should this be "count(distinct pid)"?
from form_names fn inner join
     form_items fi
     on fn.id = fi.form_name inner join
     form_records fr
     on fn.id = fr.form_name left outer join          
     form_answers fa
     on fn.id = fa.form_item and fa.form_record = fr.id
where fn.name like '%Transfer of Health Information%'
      fn.text like '%Date of Return%' and
      dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, fr.date)) = dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())) and
      fi.text like '%receiving facility%' and
      fa.id is NULL;
```

You query failed because some *other* form was satisfying the condition.

By the way, I find it much easier to have foreign keys match the name of the primary key.  Barring that, foreign keys should be the name of the table followed by `_id` or `Id`.

Comment: Gordon - I've added information about the `form_names` table. This table just list the names of the tables, not the name of the question, itself. `fn.name` is the name of the Form.

Comment: `fn.text` does not exist. `form_answers` cannot join to `form_names`, there is no direct relation. The only relationships that `form_answers` can make is between `form_question` and `form_records`. I've edited my query (specifically the outer join) to join to both `form_question` and `form_records` from `form_answers`.

Comment: @etm124 . . . It is the value `16409` in your example that also needs to be included in the join as well as the value `1147`.

Comment: the question that I am checking for no row is the `Date of Return` or value `1151`.

Comment: Gordon - you were right about joining two tables in my outer. My `fi.text` clause needs to be `like '%date of return%` not `like %receiving facility%`